# Get a vorto image

Tags: razor, umbraco

I've looked everywhere for the answer to this and it seems that it should be so simple. How can I a vorto image out?

I've tried this but nothing is outputted:

```
@Umbraco.Media(Model.Content.GetVortoValue("matchSchedulesMainImage").ToString()).Url
```

Comment: matchSchedulesMainImage is a media picker of some sort? What is output when you just do @Model.Content.GetVortoValue("matchSchedulesMainImage") ?

Comment: Hi there, yes it is a media picker. I tried that but it outputted: Umbraco.Core.Udi[];

Comment: Do you get anything if you run `Model.Content.GetVortoValue<int>("matchSchedulesMainImage")`. Also, are you able to return any other Vorto properties on this page?

Comment: It's returning a set of Udis by the look of it rather than a single one. Is it a multiple media picker?

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but I don't think you need to use vorto to get an image. Vorto only works on text. So in your example you should be able to just do this
@Umbraco.Media(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("matchSchedulesMainImage")).Url